How to store a Global variable between restarts with MongoDB
I have a $count command which increases a variable "count" by 1. Every time I reset my bot, the count goes back to 0, because I set it with let count = 0. My issue is that I don't want the variable to reset, but removing the line just leaves count undefined. How can I use MongoDB (mongoose) to store the variables previous data through resets?
My Code:
let count = 0

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.content === '$count') {
        count = count + 1;
        message.reply(`The count is now ${count}.`);
    }
});

I tried deleting the let statement, but the variable is undefined. Is there something I can set the variable to in order to keep it the same since before the restart?
Edit:
I tried creating a schema to store the variable, but it prints as "NaN." I'm not sure why it isn't a number, as I have set the "number" property on the variable.
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const globalSchema = new Schema({
    count: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
},
);

module.exports = model('Global', globalSchema)

In the other file:
const Global = require('../src/schemas/global');

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.content === '$count') {
        Global.count = Global.count + 1;
        message.reply(`The count is now ${Global.count}.`);
    }
});


You doesn't seem reading/writing to the database to persist your count value.

You have to find the document in your database, update it, then save it: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#models

Are you connecting to mongodb as it's not clear what stage you need help with? You can use the $inc operator for this.

You will need to connect to a Mongodb database, find the count in your database (a good way to do this is using the _id field) and then use this to define your count at the start of your code. then modify your incrementation function to send the incremented value to your database every time it is updated.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
